# What's the difference between "selfkill" and "suicide"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I think *selfkill* is often used in games and *suicide* in real life. Is that correct?

Comment: suicides are intentional, selfkills may also be accidental

Comment: @Nico I think self-kills are always accidental. If you're intentionally killing yourself then it's considered a suicide since it was pre-planned. But if you kill yourself from something unintentional, then it's called a self-kill. I can only think of a few places where self-kills and suicides have gray areas, and that's when you don't know about a potential way to suicide. So if CTRL+SHIFT+S _always_ kills your avatar, but you don't know that and you use that command, you suicide technically, but in your eyes it's more of a self kill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suicide is killing oneself intentionally.

*Selfkill* is only in use as slang in computer games. As well as controller ochestrated avatar death, it also includes instances where your avatar dies accidentally, e.g. falling to its death due to a misstep or rocket jumping with too little health.

Garner’s Dictionary of Legal Usage list *self-killing* (notice the hyphen) as synonymous with *suicide*. (So legally they are the same thing.)